# Read files in WP8

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

i have a problem with reading file in WP8.

```
string text;
IStorageFolder applicationFolder = ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;

IStorageFile storageFile = await applicationFolder.GetFileAsync("MyFile.txt");
IRandomAccessStream accessStream = await storageFile.OpenReadAsync();

using (Stream stream = accessStream.AsStreamForRead((int)accessStream.Size))
{
    byte[] content = new byte[stream.Length];
    await stream.ReadAsync(content, 0, (int)stream.Length);

    text = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(content, 0, content.Length);
}

return text;
```

Sometimes the `storagefile` or the `accessStream` crash without a reason.
If I debug them, it works.

I have no idea why. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm using this piece of code. The result will be the texts within your txt file, shortened into a string, so let's say your txt file contains this.

```
This
is
a test.
```

Result will be

```
This\nis\na\test.
```

Then, all you need to do is to split them up. 
    string result = null;

```
IsolatedStorageFile store = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication();
if (store.FileExists("services.txt"))
{
    using (var stream = new IsolatedStorageFileStream("services.txt", FileMode.Open, store))
    {
        using (var fileReader = new StreamReader(stream))
        {
            result = fileReader.ReadToEnd();
        }
    }
}
```

This is how i split the message.

```
string[] tmp = result.Split(new char[] { '\r', '\n', '.' });
foreach (string str in tmp)
{
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(str);
}
```

Hope this helps.